# Insert rows to DataTable from SQL table

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datatable, dataadapter

I have a `Datatable` in my C# program that I would like to `INSERT` rows from a temp table in SQL Server. The `dataAdapter.FILL()` method writes over the whole datatable. I need to keep the records that are in the `DataTable` and add records that exist in the temp table back into my `DataTable`.

I do not see a DA method for that, they all seem to go back to the SQL Server table except FILL. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about Merging your DataTables

```
DataTable dttemp = new DataTable();

dataAdapter.Fill(dtTemp);

originaldatatable.Merge(dtTemp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Now, open a database connection using the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB provider.
// The "using" statement ensures that the connection is closed no matter what.
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data      source=Northwind.mdb"))
{
    connection.Open();

// Create an OleDbDataAdapter and provide it with an INSERT command.
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Shippers (CompanyName, Phone) VALUES (@CompanyName , @Phone)", connection);
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("CompanyName", OleDbType.VarChar, 40, "CompanyName");
adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("Phone", OleDbType.VarChar, 24, "Phone");

adapter.Update(data);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it keeps throwing an exception (I'm sure it is in my conversion to my code) but before I keep going trying to make this work, what makes it Update the DATATABLE and not the SQL TABLE?  The INSERT command it generates looks to me like a it is going to the SQL table.